# Angular 6: how to subscribe data of particular json response key

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm using `Angular 6`.

I have a **contact-list.components.ts** to retrieve contacts list from the server which returns data in following JSON format.

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": "9ab849a7-25c4-41df-9ac2-f9a122eed1ad",
            "first_name": "Anshuman",
            "last_name": "Upadhyay",
            ...
            "phone_numbers": [
                {
                    "id": "0bf22da0-b880-431b-b863-c10dac6c1ea9",
                    "phone": "9718996135",
                    ...
                }
            ],
            "emails": [
                {
                    "id": "16538e03-3257-4ac6-acfc-23e7c25757b9",
                    "email": "sushilphp85@gmail.com",
                    ...
                }
            ],
            "address": [
                {
                    "id": "54ad72b5-c570-4ea0-83ce-edf162b68f23",
                    "line_1": "Nirala",
                    ...
                    "state": {
                        "id": "e9e85f3b-bf2b-46e6-9209-4548bf619c83",
                        "name": "Uttar Pradesh",
                        ...
                        "country": {
                            "id": "6305ea1d-674b-470f-b1b9-31f46ca2bbec",
                            "name": "India",
                            ...
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have defined a **contact.model.ts**

```
export class Contact {
  id: string;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  full_name: string;
  gender: string;
  date_of_birth: string;
  avatar: string;
  primary_phone: string;
  primary_email: string;
  created: string;
  modified: string;
}
```

and **contacts.component.ts** as

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ContactService} from '../contact.service';
import {Contact} from '../contact.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact-list',
  templateUrl: './contact-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact-list.component.css']
})
export class ContactListComponent implements OnInit {

  contacts: Contact[];

  constructor(
    private contactService: ContactService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getContacts();
  }

  getContacts(): void {
    this.contactService.getContacts().subscribe(
      contacts => this.contacts = contacts
    );
    console.log(this.contacts);    // prints undefined
  }

}
```

and the content of **contact.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable, of} from 'rxjs';
import {Contact} from './contact.model';
import {catchError} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {ResourceProviderService} from '../resource-provider.service';
import {AuthService} from '../auth/auth.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ContactService {

  private contactUrl = '/api/contacts/';

  private static log(message: string) {
    console.log(`ContactService: ${message}`);
  }

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private resource: ResourceProviderService,
    private auth: AuthService
  ) { }

  getContacts(): Observable<Contact[]> {
    const url = this.resource.url + this.contactUrl;

    return this.http.get<Contact[]>(url)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError('getContacts', []))
      );
  }

  private handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
      // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
      console.error(error);

      // TODO: better job of transforming error for user consumption
      ContactService.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);

      // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
      return of(result as T);
    };
  }
}
```

The JSON response is there in the network tab in the request URL of `getContacts()` but not able to save the returned data into `this.contact`.

**How can I set returned JSON data in the Contacts class object?**

Comment: This question is being asked twice per day. What you get back is an **observable**, not a list of contacts. Why? Because an HTTP request is **asynchronous**, which means you can't get the results immediately. Instead, you're notified, later, when the result is available. Just like when you grill a toast or you send an email: the grilled toast or the response is only available later, when the toaster or the email client notifies you. So of course, printing the results immediately after you've sent the request will print undefined. Move the log **inside** the subscribe callback function.

Comment: I hope you realize that the JSON you receive doesn't match, at all, the Contact interface you have defined.

Comment: @JBNizet, I have realized and correcting that structure. Actually, earlier I just wanted to store the result part of the response. That's what the question title states. I'm restructuring the class and response as well.

Comment: Also, you can see there are hierarchical data in the JSON response. Since I'm new to Angular, I'm a bit confused how to define that hierarchical structure in the class. The hierarchical data part may be some other component.

Comment: `phone_numbers: Array<PhoneNumber>;` where PhoneNumber is another class (or, preferrably, interface).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just move console.log inside the subscribe function eq.

```
getContacts(): void {
  this.contactService.getContacts().subscribe(contacts => 
  {
    this.contacts = contacts;
    console.log(this.contacts);
  }
  );
}
```

Comment: got it thanks. but is the declaration of **contact.model.ts** file correct for the JSON response format? I'm new to Angular and just exploring things inside it.

Comment: @AnujTBE no, of course not. What you receive is an object with count, next, previous and results. And you tell TypeScript that you receive an array.

Comment: That what @JBNizet wrote + you have totaly wrong structure of the contact class eg. phone numbers, emails etc. You can map that to the Contact class but you need to do that yourself by using map pipe function

Answer (score 2):

```
getContacts(): void {
    this.contactService.getContacts()
    .subscribe((contacts: Contact[]) => {

         this.contacts = contacts

         // due to async nature of observable, this.contacts gets data at some point of time
         // So, out side of subscribe block, it won't be resolved when that line executes

         console.log(this.contacts);    // should print the actual value coming from backend
    });

}
```